# has_many with foreign key in own table as an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to do a "ecommerce like" solution. When a product is defined, there are many `option_values`, e.g. whip cream => yes.

When I'm creating a `line_item`, my associations are like this.

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :shop
  ...
```

When a user chooses a product, he chooses `options_values` and a `line_item` must be created to store this.

**Currently I'm not sure what is a good way to model the `option_values` in a line item.**

My gut instinct is that a `line_item has_many option_values`, but it would seem weird to store  foreign keys in `option_values`. The other thought is that `line_item habtm option_values`.

What would be a good way to model this `line_item has_many option_values` relationship, ideally storing the reference in the `line_items` table?

Comment: I think you should use habtm association for option_values in LineItem. So option_values are stored independently from your order details etc.

Comment: Yea I thought that's what I would do, but I feel that there must be a better solution and if someone on SO must have had the same problem =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `option_values` are always boolean (whip cream => yes) you should have an `OptionValues` model with all available `option_values` and do habtm between `LineItem` and `OptionValues`.

If your option values are not always boolean (sugar => 2.spoons) then you must store this value (2.spoons) in the join model, so you should do something like this:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :line_item_option_values
   ...
end

class  LineItemOptionValue < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :line_item
   belongs_to :option_value
end

class  OptionValue < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :line_item_option_values
end
```

And have the table for `LineItemOptionValue` a field for the value of the option.

Comment: Thanks WRZ. This is what I didn't consider. That the join model might have its own need to do things like storing quantity. I'll do it this way, solves my problem.